# Mongoexport is not working for collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I am trying to export a Collection like this:

```
C:\Program Files\ConEmu>mongoexport --db test --collection person --out personTest.json
connected to: 127.0.0.1
couldn't open [personTest.json]
```

It is not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You most likely are doing this from a non-elevated command prompt, and are denied to write in Program Files.

You can:

- Supply a full path to a directory where you can write, `--out C:\Temp\personTest.json`
- `cd` to a directory where you can write and call the executable by full path: `C:\Program Files\ConEmu\mongoexport ...`
- Execute your command from an elevated prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have write permission in this directory.
Change your current location to your home directory or some other directory where you have write permission.e.g My Documents, or Desktop , or user/Andre

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following things

1.Goto `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin` or it should be any path other than mongo shell.
2. If you are in this C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin path and trying to export collection then you need to run this query `mongoexport --db test --collection special --out E:\spec.json` . After --out you need to mention path where the exported file needs to store. If you doesn't provide this it will try to store in current directory. In some systems , drive c has root permissions so at this time it will not allow you to store file.For that you need to give paths of other drive's other than this `C drive`.

3.If you are using other paths it is your wish to set the path for exporting file.You can use  `mongoexport --db test --collection special --out E:\spec.json`.  or `mongoexport --db test --collection special --out spec.json`.
4.Check into the destination path for exported file.

Hope it helps.